# Why does the value of this array element resolve to zero?

Tags: php, for-loop, output

I'm working on pagination for my website, yet I'm stuck on the following piece of code. I've been messing around with it for at least an hour, and can't seem to wrap my head around what's going on with the output.

Of course the `if` statement executes once.

And as expected the first `echo ...` returns `1`.

However, for some reason the second `echo ...` returns `0` as a float instead of `<div>1</div>` as a string...

```
$rowCount = 5;

$pgCount = ceil($rowCount / 10);

$pgParamArray["page"] = $pgCount;

$pgArray = array("", "", "", "", "");

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

  if ($pgParamArray["page"] - $i > 0) {

    echo $pgParamArray["page"] - $i;

    $pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . $pgParamArray["page"] - $i . "</div>";

    echo $pgArray[$i];

  }

}
```

- I have tried setting `$pgArray` as `array()` and `array($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $5)` with no luck.
- Even though `var_dump($pgParamArray)` returns float, I tried converting $rowCount, which is initially a string from the database, to a number anyways. No dice again.
- `echo $pgArray["0"]` also returns `0`.
- `var_dump($pgArray[0])` also returns float.
- `var_dump($pgArray)` obviously returns array.
- However, `var_dump($pgArray)` returns `array(5) { [0]=> string(7) ...`

I have absolutely zero idea why `$pgArray[0]` returns `0`, yet `var_dump($pgArray)` returns `array(5) { [0]=> string(7) ...`. That makes zero sense to me. **Anybody know why `$pgArray[0]` is resolving to `0`?**

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing the `$pgArray`? Whats the output of that.

Comment: @QuietOran yes, i have. forgot to include that in things i've tried. tried so many diff things that i've lost track. it's an array, of course. i've also `var_dumped $pgArrray[0]` which also returns float.

Comment: why are you echoing `$pgArray[$i]`? Shouldn't that just be `echo $pgArray;` ? You already assigned that same array above that.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` what does that throw back?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i'm echoing `$pgArray[$i]` because i change the value in the `if` statement in the `for` loop.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner all of the error reporting returns absolutely nothing... **-.-a**

Comment: what happens when you take the echo'd line "outside" the loop? I may not be the person for this though. Lord as my witness, I suck at arrays lol!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner strangely enough, exact same output... i'm honestly baffled. sall good dude lol i just appreciate you wanting to help out.

Comment: `$pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . ($pgParamArray["page"] - $i ). "</div>";`

Comment: Drat, too late...

Comment: @TimMorton by a hair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your statement in parenthesis seems to work for me:

```
$pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . ($pgParamArray["page"] - $i) . "</div>";
```

Without the parenthesis, it seems that the value breaks completely; the page doesn't print the `<div>` tags at all, but rather just adds a trailing `0` to the already printed `1`.

I would assume that it's due to how PHP processes string concatenation, though I wouldn't be able to give you an exact answer as to why this happens. Just to be safe, I'd always either store any equations in variables before you pass them in, or perform all operations inside of parenthesis.

That way, you won't have weird encounters like this (for example):

```
echo "<div>" . 1 + 1 . "</div>";     // returns 1
echo "<div>" . (1 + 1) . "</div>";   // returns 2
```

Comment: wow, that's it. i wish i knew i had to do that before wasting hours on this. you don't have to do that in JS :.(

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner this... :.(

Comment: Understand your pain! This is interesting to me as well. I experimented a bit more with it and updated my answer. 'tis a weird language

Comment: i believe the `<div></div>` of `<div>0</div>` obviously gets processed as HTML, which is why an echo returns `0`. but i'm dumbfounded as to why the calculation wouldn't take place unless i gave it special scope

Comment: @Anthony The reason for this behaviour hit me just after I went to bed last night.  It's pretty obvious after you see it.  I went ahead and put it in an answer for anybody who comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group the arithmetic part as mentioned in the accepted answer:
`$pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . ($pgParamArray["page"] - $i) . "</div>";`

To understand what's going on here, you need to run it on the command line:

```
php > $rowCount = 5;
php > 
php > $pgCount = ceil($rowCount / 10);
php > 
php > $pgParamArray["page"] = $pgCount;
php > 
php > $pgArray = array("", "", "", "", "");
php > 
php > for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
php { 
php {   if ($pgParamArray["page"] - $i > 0) {
php { 
php {     echo $pgParamArray["page"] - $i;
php { 
php {     $pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . $pgParamArray["page"] - $i . "</div>";
php { 
php {     echo $pgArray[$i];
php { 
php {   }
php { 
php { }
10</div>
php >
```

As you can see, the output of `echo $pgParamArray["page"] - $i;` is `1`, immediately followed by `0</div>` as the contents of `$pgArray[$i]`.

So the real issue is, what is happening to the `<div>` in

`$pgArray[$i] = "<div>" . $pgParamArray["page"] - $i . "</div>";`

After seeing the real output, the answer is a little more obvious now:  it's a grouping issue. PHP is simply taking it left to right:

```
((("<div>". $pgParamArray["page"]) - $i) . "</div>") 

((("<div>" . 1 ) - $i) . "</div>")

((("<div>1") - $i ) . "</div>")

((( 0 ) - $i ) . "</div>") 

((( 0 ) - 0 ) . "</div>")

((( 0 )) . "</div>>") 

((( "0</div>" )))
```

Comment: based on the output at the very bottom of your answer, it's still unclear to me how it resolves to zero. in the top line, `$pgParamArray["page"]` should resolve to 1, which i believe is what is carrying over to the second line as `0`? i need to learn and start using local development. would be so much more helpful in the long haul

Comment: You are correct, `$pgParamArray["page"]` evaluates to 1; however, that's not what is being evaluated.  What it's trying to subtract 0 from is `<div>1`, which evaluates to 0.  I skipped a step... I'll fix that.